# Quartz C# different class

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

I have configured Quartz in my .Net program and I have a strange issue happening that I need help with.

What happens is that, if I put the ActuationService with the constructor commented the Quartz implementation works showing the "Hello message. Otherwise, if I have the ActuationService with the constructor method (like in the code below) the message "Hello" does not show

I'm using dependency injection for the Interfaces in the constructor method and I have the following code:

What am I doing wrong ?

```
using Quartz;
using Quartz.Impl;
using Quartz.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using AAA.Service.Actuations;

    namespace AAA.Service.StartUppers
{
    public class StartUpService : IStartUpService
    {
        private readonly IScheduler _quartzScheduler;

        public StartUpService(IScheduler quartzScheduler)
        {
            this._quartzScheduler = quartzScheduler;
        }

        public async void startTasks()
        {
            try
            {

                IJobDetail deviceActuation = JobBuilder.Create<ActuationService>()
                .WithIdentity("deviceActuator", "group2")
                .Build();

                ITrigger triggerDeviceActuation = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("triggerDeviceActuation", "group2")
                .WithCronSchedule("0 0/1 * * * ?")
                .Build();

                await _quartzScheduler.ScheduleJob(deviceActuation, triggerDeviceActuation);

                await _quartzScheduler.Start();


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new System.Exception("An error ocurred - " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the class where I have the execute method

```
namespace AAA.Service.Actuations
{
    public class ActuationService : IJob
    {
        private readonly IUserRepository _userRepo;
        private readonly IDeviceRepository _deviceRepo;
        private readonly IMeasurementAdapter _measurementsAdapter;

        public ActuationService( IUserRepository userRepo, IDeviceRepository deviceRepo, IMeasurementAdapter measurementsAdapter)
         {
             this._userRepo = userRepo;
             this._deviceRepo = deviceRepo;
             this._measurementsAdapter = measurementsAdapter;
         }

        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HELLO");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The job factory does not know how to resolve the job's dependencies to be injected into the constructor.

Comment: What is being used for the dependency injection?

Comment: In the startup.cs, more specifically in the "ConfigureMyServices" method I do the services.AddTransient<Interface, ConcreteIMplementation>() for every Service. I have a bunch of other services not related with Quartz with DI and everything works fine. This problem just happens when I use Quartz

Comment: Are you using the MS DI integration package or something else? https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/microsoft-di-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

Qaurtz doesn't know how to instantiate `IUserRepository, IDeviceRepository, IMeasurementAdapter`. To use DI in Quartz, you must use the `Quartz.Extensions.DependencyInjection` package.

Call `UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory` in Quartz configuration:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Your services...

    services.AddQuartz(q =>
    {
        q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory(); 
        //Your configuration
    }
}
```

Check out the [documentation](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/microsoft-di-integration.html#installation).